# How do i run an intellij Java project from command line?

Tags: java, bash, intellij-idea, ide, development-environment

In Intellij, when i run a java project (via CTRL+SHIFT+F10) on the class that has a `public static void main` method, the project runs as expected. Now, i want to run this same file/project, but on the command line. Furthermore, i want to be able to update this file and re-run it.

I copied the command that Intellij outputs into the console, and i stuck that command on the terminal. the command looks something like this:

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Con`...... (it's an insanely long command)

Let's say my file looks like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String...args){System.out.println("hi");}
}
```

==> outputs "hi" when i run the command.

While this command runs just fine on terminal, it does NOT pick up any updates to the file. if i save the file, the previous cached files are run.

i.e. let's say now i modify the file to be:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String...args){System.out.println("GOOD BYE");}
}
```

==> the output is still "hi". even if i save the file.

I'm running the command from home directory.

How do i get the command to pick up my changes?

If i run again from intellij with the updated file, it gives the same command as previously (well, other than the port changes).

========================================================================

Update:

okay, it looks like the command is running just a .class file. But i still can't see the commands used to build the .class file. how do i do this?

Comment: I'd suggest that you turn line wrapping on for a moment.  Then you'll see a lot of the work that IntelliJ does just for that Hello World project you've got there.

Comment: @Makoto it looks like that is the command to RUN the project. by that point the `.class` file has already been generated. how do I see what Intellij does to generate this `.class` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to rebuild the project before running it if you want to see your changes.  You can use `javac` but I suggest you use a build tool like maven or gradle.

Once you have rebuilt your project you can run the latest build.

You can also create a script which first compiles your program before it runs it like IntelliJ does.

Comment: It's a gradle project. however, i can't seem to figure out how to use "gradlew" to generate the .class file. any help?